# How to use QGIS field calculator to delete style code?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am struggling with following issue:

How to delete style code before id codes *x.x.xx..* and the }s in the end?

Examples below:

```
{\fArial|b1|i0|c0|p34;A.B.11} {\fArial|b1|i0|c0|p34;A.C.1}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this expression:

regexp_substr(  "your_field_name" ,'\\;(.*)\\}' )

Comment: Thnaks but I´m now getting following message:  Eval Error:
Invalid regular expression '?(.*)?': bad repetition syntax

Comment: Sorry - that should have been: regexp_substr( "your_field_name" ,'\\;(.*)\\}' )
The slashes need to be repeated.

Comment: Thansk a lot! Worked nicely